# iOS7 swipe to delete (extract swipeout from Framework7?)

Tags: jquery, ios, frameworks, mobile-safari, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement an iOS7 (not the ugly iOS6) swipe to delete button used in native iOS and non-native framework7.

Demo (Framework7/jQuery swipe to delete): http://www.idangero.us/framework7/apps/todo7/

Has anyone besides me ever tried, or know of a way, to extract Framework7's Swipeout functionality from Framework7? Or successfully implemented a stand alone javascript solution that works the same way but not necessarily makes use of the/a heavy framework? So far, I've tried to cut and paste from the framework7.js file but with no success.

Framework7 Swipeout documentation: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/swipeout.html#.VB_eD754Pb4

I don't want to include the entire framework, just get hold of the code which allows me to swipe out an extra delete button as shown in the demo. Or as said above, a similar solution that does not make use of a framework.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I need something similar.

Comment: No not really. I ended up making my own but it turned out to be really buggy. I wouldn't suggest anyone to have multiple scrolling directions in a "fragile" web app.